# How to integrate Firebase authentication in nativescript?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, nativescript, nativescript-firebase

Getting Error during firebase init in native-script + angular. I am using native-script-plugin-firebase. It shows the following run time error:
JS: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'android' of undefined
JS: TypeError: Cannot read property 'android' of undefined

```
home.component.ts
```

```
import firebase = require("nativescript-plugin-firebase");

firebase.init({ })
        .then(
            () => {
                console.log("firebase.init done");
            },
            error => {
                console.log(`firebase.init error: ${error}`);
            }
        );
```

Comment: Does the error go away when you remove the init call to firebase? Can you share a Playground sample where the issue can be reproduced?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but the syntax should be `const firebase = require("nativescript-plugin-firebase");`

Answer (score 0):

Use below snippet:

```
firebase
  .init({
    // Optionally pass in properties for database, authentication and cloud messaging,
    // see their respective docs and 'iOSEmulatorFlush' to flush token before init.
    iOSEmulatorFlush: true,
  })
  .then(
    () => {
      // console.log("firebase.init done: " + String(res));
    },
    (error) => {
      console.log("firebase.init error: " + String(error));
    }
  )
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log("firebase init error", err);
  });
```

Comment: Consider adding more explanation on why this code will work to help us understand more instead of just pasting a code snippet :)